# How does Eclipse invoke its Ant plugin?

Tags: eclipse, ant

So I know where my Eclipse's Ant plugin invocation scripts are:

```
C:\eclipse_kepler\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\bin
```

But it has several relevant scripts to choose from, especially `ant.bat` and `ant.cmd`.

When I right-click on a build.xml and select `Run As > Ant Build`, **which** of these scripts does it invoke?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't use any of these scripts. It invokes the Ant Java code directly.

The `org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner` class actually runs Ant.

You can configure various options for Ant builds in the 'Run > External Tools Configuration....' menu in the 'Ant Build' section.